# Stdio: 'pipe' not sending data from nodejs to python; child_process and sys

Tags: python, node.js, child-process, stdio, sys

I have a nodejs app that sends image data to python. Thus, I have to use some method capable of sending large amounts of data. I am attempting to use stdio pipe to send that data. However, in python when I get the data, and attempt to do print(data), nothing is printed. Because there is 0 data received.

Here is the nodejs:

```
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  var dataToSend;
  const image3v = fs.readFileSync('jeff (1).jpg');
  const image4v = fs.readFileSync('falsified2 (1).jpg');

  var obj = {obj1: image3v, obj2: image4v};
  const python = spawn('python', ['script1.py'], { stdio: 'pipe' });

  python.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
  python.stdin.end();

  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    dataToSend = data.toString();
  });
  
  python.stderr.on('data', data => {
    console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
  });
  
  python.on('exit', (code) => {
    console.log(dataToSend);
  });
});
```

Here is the python:

```
import sys
import json
print('python begins')

import select

data = sys.stdin.read()
data = json.loads(data)
# attempt to wait until all data is received
while not data:
    if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0.0)[0]:
        data = sys.stdin.read()
        data = json.loads(data)


print("Data received from Node.js:")
print(data)
```

In the console, nothing is printed for print(data), leading me to believe there is an issue in sending the data.

Thanks.

EDIT: The issue is that the image data is too large to send. Aside from optomization, what methods do I have to make the data send better?

Comment: Any reason not to send the path to the images in stdin (instead of the image content) and read the image content in your script?

Comment: Sadly, yes, since the images are never meant to be saved since they are sent by the user. The program just uses the images, never saves them though. So itd be preferred to avoid this, but if we cant find a solution then I might have to write them and save them, send the path and use in python, then delete those files when they are done being used. However, might not be too efficient.

Comment: You can split writing to stdin into several chunks by split json string and calling `python.stdin.write` multiple times before calling `python.stdin.end`. Note that you might also need to buffer stdout into an array instead of a string